# Hardware Integration Testing in Xamarin Test Cloud

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin-test-cloud

We would like to have functional tests which require our app to connect with external hardware device.

We know that we can record the test cases and run then with mobile device connected via USB from Visual Studio.

But, can anybody confirm if Xamarin Test Cloud provides any way of setting up Test Server with set of mobile devices to perform Hardware connectivity/bluetooth communication testing with Mobile App under Test?

Thanks
Dhavan

Answer (score 1):

No, they do not provide this at the moment.